# Google Drive files are being flagged as inappropriate in Service Worker account

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Drive/Sheets APIs (v3 via Python) to automate some core aspects of a business, in which live insights are saved to a Google Sheet that customers can view.

This process is entirely automated and the flow goes something like this:

- Service Worker copies template in root Google Drive, to its own drive.
- Initial Values are set, like customer name and some other metadata to the sheet.
- Sheet is shared with other Service Workers, and to the staff of the company using a Google Org group so that they can view/edit/share as they would a regular file that they own.

This has worked with 0 issues for about 2 or 3 years now, until today. All newly copied sheets are being flagged as inappropriate, which disallows sharing to any user, at all. Since the service worker is the technical owner of the sheet, it cannot be accessed via the Google Drive UI to request a review.

There is nothing inappropriate about the content, the sheets simply contain analytics and graphs that are updated with new entries. The API errors do not give any insight into exactly what tripped the alarm, just that it as a whole is "inappropriate".

I am at a loss here since it seems the only way to resolve this is to request a review from the Drive UI, which isn't possible since the ownership transfer fails from the original service account owner. I wanted to post here to get any possible insight before enrolling in a support plan to get some 1on1 technical support. Any help/ideas is greatly appreciated.

Things I have tried so far:

- Sharing with `'sendNotificationEmail': False` on the `service.permissions().create()` call.
- Duplicating the file with a `.copy()` operation and re-sharing (same issue)
- Transferring ownership to a user account (rejected, for the same reason)

Comment: If no recent changes has been made, maybe you should get technical support. They should know *and share* the reason(s) about why the sheets are flagged as *inappropriate*.

Comment: Upon scouring the internet, it seems multiple users are also being affected as per [this recently submitted issue on the Google Issue Tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264308667). Furthermore, I agree that maybe it would be better to reach out to a dedicated technical support to get expert assistance about the matter.

Comment: I apologize for taking a while to get back here, but yes, this actually ended up being an error in Google's system. After I contacted support it was resolved after a few days.

Comment: Hi so what was the solution? I been with this issue for hours too